# How should I include these functions in AllValidate function?

Tags: javascript, html

When click on the submit button, I want to make sure it can detect if the user correctly entered the forms through the functions below, if user did not enter correctly it can stop the form from being submit.
What should I include in my AllValidate function?*

```js
<button name="regbtn" id="register_btn" class="reg_btn" type="submit" onclick="AllValidate()">Register</button>
```

```js
function addressValidate()
{
    var address = document.getElementById("reg_add").value;
    var space   = /^\s*$/;
    var flag    = true;

    if(address.match(space))
    {
        document.getElementById("add_error").innerHTML = "Address is required.";
        document.getElementById("reg_add").style.border = "2px solid red";
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("add_error").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("reg_add").style.border = "2px solid #f0f0f0";
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

```js
function phoneValidate()
{
  var phoneNo = document.getElementById("reg_phone").value;
  var pattern = /[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}/;
  var space   = /^\s*$/;
  var flag    = true;

  if(phoneNo.match(space))
  {
    document.getElementById("phone_error").innerHTML = "Phone number is required.";
    document.getElementById("reg_phone").style.border = "2px solid red";
    flag = true;
  }
  else if(phoneNo.match(pattern))
  {
    document.getElementById("phone_error").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("reg_phone").style.border = "2px solid #f0f0f0";
    flag = false;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("phone_error").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number.";
    document.getElementById("reg_phone").style.border = "2px solid red";
    flag = true;
  }
  return flag;
}
```

```js
AllValidate()
{

}
```

Comment: This is the most laborious method to validate a form. HTML5 offers internal mechanisms that do this much better with automatic error messages and that only require a few lines of code, if any. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Thank you Mister Jojo for the useful information. I just want to have the error messages to be displayed for my project purposes.

Comment: I have added a response to show you this way

Answer (score 0):

First you have to edit the submit button as follows

```
<button name="regbtn" id="register_btn" class="reg_btn" type="submit" onclick="return AllValidate()">Register</button>
```

Then your `AllValidate()` function follows

```
function AllValidate(){
   return (addressValidate() && phoneValidate());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Julius. The problem here is the form still submits when the fields aren't entered correctly. How should I prevent the form from submitting when the flag is true on one of the functions or is there any other way?

Comment: When you modify your `submit` button from `onclick = "AllValidate()"`  to `onclick = "return AllValidate()"`, untill the `AllValidate()` function returns true, your form will not submit. In my `AllValidate()` function, the form should submit if and only if  `addressValidate() == true && phoneValidate() == true`. Tell me if problem still persist for another option

Answer (score 0):

use that way, with HTML5 *auto validation*

- use attribute **required**
- use attribute **pattern** ( you can also use input type="tel")

sample code

```js
// personnalize your error message 
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.reg_phone.oninvalid=_=>
  {
  let msg = (myForm.reg_phone.value.trim() === '')
          ? 'Phone number is required.'
          : 'Please enter a valid phone number.'
  myForm.reg_phone.setCustomValidity(msg)
  }

// just to verify input...
myForm.onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault()  // just for test here (disable submit)

  // shwo values
  console.clear()
  console.log( 'name :' , myForm.reg_name.value )  
  console.log( 'address :' , myForm.reg_add.value )  
  console.log( 'Phone :' , myForm.reg_phone.value )    
  }
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 18em;
  }
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: .7em;
  }
label * {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  }
label input,
label textarea {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-size:1.2em;
  padding: .2em;
  }
label input  {
  width: 9em;
  }
button {
  margin: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<form action="..." name="my-form">
  <label>
    name :
    <input type="text" name="reg_name" required>
  </label>
  <label>
    address :
    <textarea name="reg_add" rows="4" required placeholder="address"></textarea>
  </label>
  <label>
    Phone :
    <input type="text" name="reg_phone" required pattern="\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}" placeholder="___-____-____">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```